# GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS toggle when texture used twice

Tags: opengl

I have made an OpenGL scene with two objects:

- A cube that acts as an evironment map
- A small cube that the camera always points to.

**Both cubes are using cubemap textures.**

[image]

- When you press "1" the texture of the background toggles between the "forest" and the texture with colors.
- When you press "2" we toggle the texture of the small cube in the same way.
- When you press "S" we enable/disable `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS`.

I have noticed something weird. If I press "S" when each cube uses a different texture unit, the toggle of `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS` works fine. However, if both cubes have the same texture, the "S" toggle doesn't work - it just has the enablement that it used to have.

It is not a problem for me because I would normally use only one cubemap (and probably nobody needs to toggle `seamless` on the fly). But I'm curious why this could be happening. Is it expected behavior?

[image]

EDIT: I just made a repo on github. It's all in main.cpp but it uses some libraries.

https://github.com/tuket/stackoverflow_question_cubemap/blob/master/src/main.cpp

Comment: My guess would be that the error is in your code, which you haven't posted, so...

Comment: @derhass I just modified my question with a link to the code. I have tried in Windows 10 and it doesn't happen there (I was trying with Ubuntu 18.04 before). So either it's a driver bug in Ubuntu, or my code is wrong and the Windows driver is more permisive.